# Cloudera Manager UI not working on port 7180

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am installing Cloudera Manager by using this [link](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/manager/4-x/4-8-6/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_path_A.html)  its showing installation successful.but `http://<server_hostname>:7180/` is not working. I checked 
1) Firewall -disabled
2) Selinux - disabled

netstat -a giving:

```
tcp        0      0 *:7180                      *:*                 LISTEN
```

But browser is not able to open Cloudera Manager UI.
I also checked log files no any error and cloudera-scm-server is in running state.

Comment: check iptables status

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaReddy I checked iptables and stopped it. Also I opened few ports which needed by cloudera manager.

Comment: Try this nc -v hostname or ip 7180 and post output

Comment: nc -v my_ip 7180 didn't work,                                                                         I tried nc -l my_ip 7180                                                                            giving 'nc: Address already in use'

Comment: Are you getting any connection refused issue while running nc -v hostname 7180..?

Comment: output                                                                                                                 Connection to hostname 7180 port [tcp/*] succeeded!